# Google Chrome exstension chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, tabs

Problem: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onUpdated' of undefined

Google Chrome extension

My code:

**main.js**

I have a function getCookie and setcookie

```
var _a = getCookie("a");

if (_a != "") {
/// do something
} else {


chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId , info , tab) {
if (info.status == "complete") {

   var _a = document.getElementsByName('id_loaded_page')[0].value;
       setCookie("_a", value, 1);
       console.log("_a: " +_a);


   }
});

}
```

Comment: There is no question here to begin with; and on Stack Overflow questions of the format "here's my code (code dump) it doesn't work, help" are **not welcome**. Edit your post to contain a single, answerable question, and add a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with only relevant code. Also read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide.

Answer (score 10):

You are calling `chrome.tabs` from a Content Script.

By [design](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch), content scripts are [not allowed access](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) to most of the Chrome APIs.

You need to make a background page to access `chrome.tabs`, but in your particular case you don't even need that wrapper: you're injecting at `"document_end"`, which should mean that all static DOM is already loaded

And if the DOM node you are looking for is dynamically added, it may not exist when "complete" fires for a tab. You will need to listen to [DOM mutations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11546242/934239).