# How to listen for url change with Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a Google Chrome extension to automate some common tasks. The functionality I want is as follows:

1. Create a new tab and navigate to my webmail
2. enter username and password
3. click "submit" button
4. Wait until the webmail page appears, and choose the "roundcube" client.

I have completed steps 1,2,and 3 and they work. I am having a lot of trouble trying to listen for the url change after my credentials are submitted so that the function that selects roundcube client can run

I know I can run a script when client selection page appears by adding to my manifest but I want to use "chrome.tabs.executeScript" instead so that roundcube is chosen only if I run the script from the chrome extension and not if I go to client selection page manually.

Here is my manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name"       : "Chrome Autobot",
  "description": "This extension will run various automation scripts for google chrome",
  "version"    : "1.0",

  "browser_action" : {
    "default_icon" : "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "index.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "webNavigation",
    "tabs",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
  ]
}
```

Here is my chrome script:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    "Use Strict";

    var openWebmail = function() {
        chrome.tabs.create({
            url: 'http://mywebmaillogin.com:2095/'
        }, function() {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "scripts/openEmail.js"});
        });
        chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(){
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "scripts/openEmail.js"});
            alert('i work');
        });
    };

    var init = $('.script-init');
    init.on('click', function() {
        openWebmail();
    });

});
```

and here is the content script to be executed as a callback of tab creation (when the email login page is fetched and the DOM has loaded), and also when the email credentials are submitted and the client selection page's DOM has loaded (which is not working right now)

```
var openEmail = function() {
    var loc = window.location.href;
    if(loc === 'http://mywebmaillogin.com:2095/') {
        var submit = document.getElementById('login_submit');
        user.value = 'myusername';
        pass.value = 'mypassword';
        if(user.value === 'myusername' && pass.value === 'mypassword') {
            submit.click();
        }
        else {
            openEmail();
        }
    }
    if(loc.indexOf('http://mywebmaillogin:2095/') > -1 && loc.indexOf('login=1') > -1) {
        alert('I work');
    }
}()
```

any help would be appreciated... thanks!

Answer (score 103, accepted):

As mentioned by [@NycCompSci](https://stackoverflow.com/users/485953), you cannot call the chrome api from content scripts. I was able to pass api data to content scripts with message passing though, so thought I'd share that here. First call `onUpdated` in background.js:

#### Manifest

```
{
  "name": "My test extension",
  "version": "1",

  // Use background.scripts for manifest V2
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "background": {
    "scripts":["background.js"]
  },

  // Use background.service_worker for manifest V3
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  }

  // "tabs" permissions is required
  "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ]

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "js": ["contentscript.js"]
    }
  ],
}
```

#### background.js

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function
  (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    // read changeInfo data and do something with it (like read the url)
    if (changeInfo.url) {
      // do something here

    }
  }
);
```

Then you can expand that script to send data (including the new url [and other chrome.tabs.onUpdated info](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onUpdated)) from background.js to your content script like this:

#### background.js

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(
  function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    // read changeInfo data and do something with it
    // like send the new url to contentscripts.js
    if (changeInfo.url) {
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage( tabId, {
        message: 'hello!',
        url: changeInfo.url
      })
    }
  }
);
```

Now you just need to listen for that data in your content script:

#### contentscript.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    // listen for messages sent from background.js
    if (request.message === 'hello!') {
      console.log(request.url) // new url is now in content scripts!
    }
});
```

Comment: What “callback” are you referring to? It could be that your permissions aren’t allowing data transfer, so make sure your manifest is setup like the above. I’d suggest starting with the above example and tweaking it because it definitely works in a fresh extension.

Comment: I have all permissions, including tabs, but in this schema I don´t received any call in function. Sad.

Comment: Sorry, Marcelo, you’re not being very specific so it’s hard to be helpful here. I would suggest trouble shooting by adding a `console.log(data)` on the first line within the function, where `data` is the data you’re trying to use, and view the console to see if it’s there. If not you’ll most likely find an error that you can search for help :)

Comment: @ztrat4dkyle how to fire message on first page load too?

Comment: Hi @RTW it's not super clear what you're asking, I think you should open a new issue for your question and provide some examples.

Comment: This is a good approach, but the `changeInfo` object only had the `status` property in my case, so went with @SynergyChen answer---where you test for the `changeInfo.status` property, and then get the URL from within the content script after the message is conveyed.

Comment: is there any way to listen for url change in iframe? I see only "loading" and "complete" state in logs, but not url.

Comment: @van9petryk I'm not 100% sure but it's best to open a new question for that

Comment: @ztrat4dkyle i found that it can be done with chrome.webNavigation https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/background_pages/#filters

Comment: Late, but @KeithDC or anyone with the same problem. You need to add "tabs" as a permission in the manifest.json to enable "url" property in the changeInfo object.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/66055883/2063755 to get this to work with manifest v3.

Comment: Thanks @DavidKlempfner I updated the manifest example above 

Answer (score 17):

use [chrome.tabs.onUpdated](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onUpdated)

**Maifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "My test extension",
  "version": "1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "background": {
    "scripts":["background.js"]
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "js": ["contentscript.js"]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ]
}
```

**contentscript.js**

```
 chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    alert('updated from contentscript');
 });
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    alert('updated from background');
});
```

Comment: Why you need to add this tabs.onUpdated listener twice, at contentscript.js and background.js respectively?

Comment: You don't have to use both, pick the one where you need to handle it. Note: In `background.js` the callback function receives the same parameters.

Comment: The contentscript.js doesn't work, you cannot call chrome api from content scripts, see this for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24024682/google-chrome-exstension-chrome-tabs-onupdated-addlistener

Answer (score 7):

Based on / Thanks to @ztrat4dkyle's answer, what works for me:

### manifest.json

```
{
  ...
  "background": {
    "scripts":["background.js"]
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ]
}
```

### background.js

```js
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
  // ...

  chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    // changeInfo object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/onUpdated#changeInfo
    // status is more reliable (in my case)
    // use "alert(JSON.stringify(changeInfo))" to check what's available and works in your case
    if (changeInfo.status === 'complete') {
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {
        message: 'TabUpdated'
      });
    }
  })
});
```

### content.js

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request.message === 'TabUpdated') {
    console.log(document.location.href);
  }
})
```