# .click() callback function explained

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am making a Google Chrome extension and I am trying to use the `.click()` function within one of my script. The click function should click a link which redirects me to another page. Once I have been redirected, I would like to send a `chrome.runtime` message.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('example-link')[1].click(function() {
       console.log("Hello World");
        let data = {
            type: "example"
        }
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({...data}); 

    });
```

So far the page redirects, but the console.log() doesn't show and the runtime message doesn't send. 
I am not sure whether I have misunderstood the purpose of the callback function or whether the scripts stops running because I am on a new page.

Any explanation / help would be appreciated.

Comment: Problem here is the fact you want to send a message on the next page load. click() does not have a callback.

Comment: So on a new page load, this script gets loaded again from fresh and so the callback in never called? Or does the .click() function not have a callback at all?How might I solve this?

Comment: click has no callback, it just triggers the action. Somehow you need to call it on the next page load. I am not a big chrome extension developer so I really can not help. Going to be something with load or update in the tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`click()` doesn't take a callback.

In order to detect navigation you need:

1. to listen for an `onUpdated` event (see [How to listen for url change with Chrome Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34957319/how-to-listen-for-url-change-with-chrome-extension).)
2. then `click()` to trigger the navigation

Comment: I ended up listening for the change in my background script: 

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    

  if(tab.url !== undefined && changeInfo.status == "complete"){

    

  }
  

})