# Chrome extensions: Use the "background.service_worker" key instead manifest_version 3

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

When trying to install a chrome extension using manifest_version 3, I am unable to install as I keep getting the error:

> The "background.scripts" key cannot be used with manifest_version 3.
> Use the "background.service_worker" key instead

or

> The "background.persistent" key cannot be used with manifest_version
> 3. Use the "background.service_worker" key instead.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Manifest V3 no longer supports background pages. Instead it now supports a new feature called service workers.

The key `background` in your manifest.json can no longer contain the field `persistent`, and also update the value from `scripts` to `service_worker`. Service worker cannot contain an array but can only contain a single string value.

Eg:

```
{
  "name": "Test",
  "description" : "Test Chrome Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  }
}
```

Ref: [Manifest V3 Migration Checklist](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/mv3-migration-checklist/)

Comment: So what do you do if you have multiple background scripts?

Comment: @orschiro Multiple background 'scripts' don't exist in v3. There can only be a single 'service_worker'. https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/migrating_to_service_workers/

Comment: @orschiro Use `importScripts`

Comment: Use content_scripts in the manifest to load additional javascript files.

Comment: Oh can't they just make an api that is implementation independent so it can just stay the same for once.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy to solve.
Are you using...

```
"background": {
        "scripts": [
             "background.js"
         ],
         "persistent": false
    },
```

- Or another method to add background on Google extension.
  JUST WRITE IT...

  "background": {
  "service_worker": "background.js"
  },

I hope this will help you to solve your problem. If not Please message me here.

Comment: Does not work with manifest_version 3